# Setup development architecture (best pratices)

Tags: php, architecture

I’m searching for a method to build a development architecture. Only i dont know the best pratices.

**Note**: i'm working with the symfony framework

Imagine you have multiple website, must all of these websites have their  own database and cms. But when you need to change a column in the DB, you’ve to change it to all DBS. Or is it beter to have one central DB, where you could save data based on company_id.

And what to do with code reusability. For example i’ve created a new feature for website 1, how could i make this feature reachable for all my other sites without updating all websites separately.

I hoop you co-developers could help me out with above questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of having separate DB for each separate site has two major benefits: resilience and flexibility.

- If one of your projects gets compromised and someone is able to corrupt the database, that same person would not be able to bring down your entire infrastructure. And a developer making a minor fuckup in an `UPDATE` query  can't affect the other sites either.
- When one of your sites manages to grow unexpectedly, with separate databases it is extremely simple to migrate it to a different hardware.

As for the updates in structure, those SQL changes should be documented anyway, so each of your project should have some migration scripts for doing it. Those scripts then can be executed by the automated deployment code.

As for code re-usability .. well ... you should separate those reusable fragments in their own libraries, put then in your private repositories and then just connect them using [composer's configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs). That way you can roll out the changes both incrementally and all at once.

Comment: Could you explain automated deployment for updating Sql Some more in depth

Comment: What if i've different databases for different sites and thouse sites belongs to one main site. How could I use consolidation or retrieve data from the main site to get data from the child sites?

Comment: @Bham depends on what you mean by "retrieve". If you are just tracking info, then I would instead have each of those slave-sites to provide an API, that the master-site can use for retrieving various reports.